# How to use existing UHD function calls in a custom OOT module in Gnu Radio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, uhd

I am making a custom OOT module called **test3** in GNU Radio which needs to use some uhd functions.

For example, I need to call the uhd::set_thread_priority_safe() function, so I import the thread.hpp file:

```
#include <uhd/utils/thread.hpp>
```

Since the function call is in the uhd namespace, so I try to use the namespace to call the function:

```
namespace gr {
  namespace test3 {
    using namespace uhd;
    .
    .
    .
    int get_time_impl::work(int noutput_items,
    gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
    gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
    {
        uhd::set_thread_priority_safe();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But doing this does not work, and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'test3' has no attribute 'get_time'
```

But when I remove the uhd function call, the error goes away.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you follow the wiki and used the command `gr_modtool add ...` as it shows there for your C++ OOT module?

Comment: @hesham_EE Yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by the following steps.

1. In gr-module/CMakeLists.txt, I added 'find_package(UHD)' in the 'find gnuradio build dependencies' section.
2. In gr-module/lib/CMakeLists.txt, I updated the target link libraries command to 'target_link_libraries(gnuradio-module gnuradio::gnuradio-runtime UHD::UHD)'.

After running cmake and make commands after the above changes, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use `using namespace uhd;`! You're not even making use of that imported namespace, so it's totally useless, and it risks that you override things within your scope with elements from the `uhd` namespace. As you currently do, access to elements from that namespace works simply by specifying the namespace when accessing, as in `uhd::set_thread_priority_safe`.

Rule of thumb: `using namespace xyz;` is very rarely a good idea. Avoid it.

Whether or not that is the problem here is impossible to tell.

Comment: I was using the function as it is before but it was giving the same error. So I thought that maybe its a namespace issue. I have now removed the namespace line, but am still stuck with the same issue.

Comment: well, the problem is that from the code you share, it's really impossible to see what might be going wrong. Did you add a python binding for that method? Does it work? Is there something generally wrong with the python binding? did the installation go well?

Comment: I have pushed my code to this repository: https://github.com/MobiZaman/gr-test3/blob/main/lib/get_time_impl.cc. I am basically doing nothing here. When I remove the uhd function call, the block works and runs perfectly fine in GRC. But when I add that call, I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: Also the make commands all work fine, the error is only shown in GRC.

Comment: do you link against UHD?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by linking against UHD?

Comment: I made the custom block by following the instructions on this page: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/OutOfTreeModules. Am I supposed to link to uhd while calling cmake?