# How to solve the CMake warning for Volk and UHD package?

Tags: cmake, gnuradio, uhd

I am trying to create a custom block in GNU Radio which also needs to use UHD. As mentioned at this [link](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html#build_apps), I added the following line to gr-module/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(UHD "3.10.0")
```

But when I call the `cmake../` command, I get the following two warnings:

1.The first one is for Volk.

```
    CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
      The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (VOLK) does
      not match the name of the calling package (Volk).  This can lead to
      problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
      (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /home/sohaib/prefix-3.8/lib/cmake/volk/VolkConfig.cmake:32 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
      /home/sohaib/prefix-3.8/lib/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake:46 (find_dependency)
      CMakeLists.txt:89 (find_package)
    This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

2.The second one is for UHD.

```
    CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
      The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PkgConfig)
      does not match the name of the calling package (UHD).  This can lead to
      problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
      (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:70 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      /home/sohaib/prefix-3.8/lib/cmake/uhd/UHDConfig.cmake:42 (include)
      /home/sohaib/prefix-3.8/lib/cmake/gnuradio/FindUHD.cmake:43 (find_package)
      CMakeLists.txt:90 (find_package)
    This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I built a custom block in GNU Radio a few weeks ago, and was not getting any warnings at that time. If I remove the `find_package(UHD "3.10.0")` line from CMakeLists.txt, I only get the warning for Volk.

How can this warning be solved?

Comment: The UHD warning went away after adding proper commands in CMakeList files, as mentioned in my answer to my question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566050/how-to-use-existing-uhd-function-calls-in-a-custom-oot-module-in-gnu-radio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't them (you could look for `Volk` instead of `VOLK`, but it might break things in other places) - you also don't have to, it's just warnings, so no action is needed.